# How to identify the attached devices through USB

Tags: java, android, usb, tablet

[image]I am developing USB to serial app, where mobile will attached with USB hub, and this hub is connected with with other devices through CP2102 cable. I am able to identify all devices and can read and write also. But the problem is all have same Vendor and product ID and other information also. And USB port number is also changing if we disconnect and connect. 
So is there any way to identify the attached devices. Let me know if any other information required here.
I am using this example for development.

http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/

Comment: Yes, by the VID & PID... so what exactly is your question?  Do you need a database of VIDs and PIDs?  You can find such with a search engine.

Comment: I am using same Cp2102 cable so for every device is showing same product and vendor id "0x10C4 / 0xEA60: CP210x UART Bridge". I need to identify which devices connected to which port(like scanner, printer, weighing indicator).

Comment: @ChrisStratton , Now I have attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AN721](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN721.pdf), there is a tool that goes with this document that Silicon Labs provides to so you can customize your device's VID and PID, serial number and device strings. Serial number might be the easiest way to make your development devices unique, if you change the VID/PID then you'll need to create a custom driver with those new settings to get your device back.